# Maximum decreasing adjacent elements - failing on array [10,11,12]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm getting all tests passing with this solution except for the array [10,11,12]. I'm stuck. Thanks for your help

**The problem:**

> Given an array of integers, find the maximal absolute difference between any two of its adjacent elements.

**The example:**

> For inputArray = [2, 4, 1, 0], the output should be
>   arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference(inputArray) = 3.

**My failing test:**

> Input:
>
> inputArray: [10, 11, 13]
>
> Output:
>   0
>
> Expected Output:
>   2
>
> Console Output:
>   Empty

```js
function arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference(arr) {
    var dif = 0;
    var max = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        dif = arr[i] - arr[i+1];
        if(dif > max){
            max = dif;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the exercise:

> Given an array of integers, find the maximal **absolute** difference between any two of its adjacent elements.

Thus your code should look like this:

```
function arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference(arr) {
    var dif = 0;
    var max = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        dif = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i+1]);
        if(dif > max){
            max = dif;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: AH! I get it now, 10-11 would be -1 which is less than 0, therefore max remains 0. Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of the differences between each element and its next sibling in the array and then pass the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) array into `Math.max`, like so:

The important piece is to get the **absolute value** of the difference between the numbers, so you do not end up with negatives. I believe that is what was causing you issues.

```js
function arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference(arr) {
    var differences = arr.map((elem, index) => {
        if (arr[index+1] != null) {
            return Math.abs(elem - arr[index+1]);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    return Math.max(...differences);
}

console.log(arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference([10, 11, 13]));
console.log(arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference([1, 5, 3]));
console.log(arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference([4, 8, 16]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array with a copy from the second element on and return the max value of the delat or last delta.

```js
function maxDelta(array) {
    return array.slice(1).reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        return Math.max(Math.abs(array[i] - a), r);
    }, 0);
}

console.log(maxDelta([10, 11, 12])); // 1
console.log(maxDelta([2, 4, 1, 0])); // 3
console.log(maxDelta([10, 11, 13])); // 2
```

Comment: Thanks Nina! I appreciate you helping me find a solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

The topic states decreasing while you ask for difference in the question body. I'll pick the second and proceed. You can do as follows;

```js
var a   = [10, 11, 13],
    res = Math.max(...Array(a.length-1).fill().map((_,i) => Math.abs(a[i]-a[i+1])));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: My apologies! I misspoke. I'll make the edits now. Thanks! Quick question, what does the ... do?

Comment: @Almost_Ashleigh That's the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator. In this case it spreads the array items as arguments to the `Math.max()` function. So `Math.max(1,2,3,4)` is essentially same with `Math.max(...[1,2,3,4])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference(inputArray):
   
        max_diff = inputArray[1] - inputArray[0]
        dif =[]
        for i in range( 1, len(inputArray) ):      
                
                if (abs(inputArray[i-1] - inputArray[i]) > max_diff ):               
                    max_diff = abs(inputArray[i-1] - inputArray[i])
                    dif.append(max_diff)
                    print(max_diff)
               
        return max_diff
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce()` method for this

```js
function findM(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
    if (arr[i + 1] || arr[i + 1] == 0) {
      var diff = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]);
      if (diff > r) r = diff
    }
    return r;
  }, 0)
}

console.log(findM([10, 11, 13]))
console.log(findM([2, 4, 1, 0]))
```

Comment: You need to null check `arr[i+1]`, not just check for truthy. If `arr[i+1]` = 0, this fails. Case: `findM([2,4,5,0])`